# How do I listen to mouse clicks from RelatedItemLineMarkerInfo?

Tags: intellij-plugin

I need to run a custom action when my marker is clicked.

I tried, according to tutorial,

```
NavigationGutterIconBuilder<PsiElement> builder =
        NavigationGutterIconBuilder.create(LessonScriptIcons.PUZZLE).
                setTarget(this).
                setTooltipText("Navigate to component");

RelatedItemLineMarkerInfo<PsiElement> m = builder.createLineMarkerInfo(this);
```

But I can't figure out how to get to the marker's navigation handler, or otherwise listen to this marker's events. (The cursor moving to the beginning of "this" element is a slightly undesired, but unimportant side effect that would be nice to suppress).

Then I tried this:

```
RelatedItemLineMarkerInfo marker =  new RelatedItemLineMarkerInfo(this, getTextRange(), MyIcons.VOLUME, 0, tooltipProvider, handler, GutterIconRenderer.Alignment.CENTER, new ArrayList<GotoRelatedItem>());
```

This approach allows me to listen to the marker's mouse clicks. However, now I am experiencing a peculiar problem: whenever the marked line of code is edited, this results in duplicate, triplicate, etc. markers in the gutter.

What's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to specify a pass.

```
int pass = Pass.UPDATE_OVERRIDEN_MARKERS;

RelatedItemLineMarkerInfo marker =  new RelatedItemLineMarkerInfo(this, getTextRange(), MyIcons.VOLUME, pass, tooltipProvider, handler, GutterIconRenderer.Alignment.CENTER, new ArrayList<GotoRelatedItem>());
```

I had to use `Pass.UPDATE_OVERRIDEN_MARKERS` even though IntelliJ marked it as deprecated and said it will be removed shortly (see the link below). However, the constant recommended by IntelliJ, `Pass.LINE_MARKERS`, results in duplicate markers.

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/analysis-impl/src/com/intellij/codeHighlighting/Pass.java